# Plumbing re-routed through attic

Tags: plumbing, insulation, pex

We recently had a leak under our slab foundation and ended up going with rerouting the plumbing through our attic. After it was done, we have noticed that there is now a distinct odor (of the PEX pipes) from the water in our home (That wasn't there before). Will this go away eventually?

Also, we are not in a freeze zone by any means (South Carolina). But the new water lines in the attic are on top of the insulation and we have noticed that the cold water is also warmer than usual. Would insulating the cold water lines help with this? Should I worry about the new lines degenerating over time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the pipes or some of them aren't genuine XLPE?  Some other plastics can cause odors and flavors.  Maybe it's just the natural smell of your water, more evident because it's being heated in the attic.   If you put a glass of it in the fridge does the smell go away?

Answer (score 2):

I Build homes in Arizona and use 100% PEX in construction. To be honest with you I have never noticed any odor at all from the pipe so my guess is the odor must dissipate. I lived in a house that was PEX as well and did not notice a smell. I imagine it could be different if you are already living in an enclosed home when the PEX is installed, but there are no solvents or glues used so I'm still at a loss for where the smell could be coming. I hope this helps. You might reach out to UPONOR based in Minneapolis. I think they are the manufacturers.